# Dispatching same action multiple times concurrently on componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a question about redux-saga, here is my problem. When I’m rendering a list on React, I’m dispatching the exact same saga multiple times concurrently for the same API call. I’m wondering if there is a way to tell saga to automatically cancel the duplicates and only call one of them.
Cheers.

Comment: check takeLatest effect

Comment: When i use takeLatest, only the last action is triggered. I want all actions to be trigger not concurrently, but one by one (each action waits for the end of the previous one to start)

Answer (score 0):

Check about **[takeLatest](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/)** redux-saga/effects. This Spawns a saga on each action dispatched to the Store that matches the pattern. After spawning a task once, it blocks until spawned saga completes and then starts listening for a pattern again. Hope it helps. **Happy Coding!!**

Comment: When i use takeLatest, only the last action is triggered. I want all actions to be trigger not concurrently, but one by one (each action waits for the end of the previous one to start)